# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Hello I'm new in android so can you please help me with my error. The error occurs when 
I'm gonna start the game so here's my logcat the database and the activity

Logcat

> > > > 08-06 04:02:31.350: E/AndroidRuntime(8261): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> > > >
> > > > > > > 08-06 04:02:31.350: E/AndroidRuntime(8261): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.windowcard/com.example.windowcard.Grade1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
> > > > > > >               08-06 04:02:31.350: E/AndroidRuntime(8261):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:127)
> > > > > > >               08-06 04:02:31.350: E/AndroidRuntime(8261):     at com.example.windowcard.dbHelp.(dbHelp.java:39)
> > > > > > >               08-06 04:02:31.350: E/AndroidRuntime(8261):     at com.example.windowcard.Grade1.(Grade1.java:41)

Database

```
package com.example.windowcard;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
 import android.util.Log;


   public class dbHelp extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String TAG = "dbHelp";
private static String DB_PATH = "";

private static String DB_NAME = "sample";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

private final Context myContext;

/**
 * Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 * @param context
 */
public dbHelp(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1); //

    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    this.myContext = context;
}   

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    myContext.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(!dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        this.close();
        try{
            copyDataBase();
            Log.e(TAG, "create Database database created"); 
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            throw new Error ("Error Copying Database");

        }

    }

}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase(){


    File dbFile = new File (DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + " " + dbFile.exists());
    return dbFile.exists();

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
    // myDatabase =
    SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
    return myDataBase != null;

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

// Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
// You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
// to you to create adapters for your views.

public Cursor getAllGrade1(){

    this.openDataBase();
    String sql = "Select * from gr1";
    Cursor  c = myDataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}
public String getScore(int score){
    this.openDataBase();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM gr1 WHERE _id =" + score;
    Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("score"));
}
public String getMistakes(int Errors){
    this.openDataBase();
    String sql="SELECT * FROM gr1 WHERE _id=" + Errors;
    Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Errors"));
}

    }
```

Activity

```
            package com.example.windowcard;

            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.Collections;
            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.app.AlertDialog;
            import android.content.DialogInterface;
            import android.content.Intent;
            import android.database.Cursor;
            import android.media.MediaPlayer;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.os.Handler;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
            import android.widget.Button;
            import android.widget.EditText;
            import android.widget.TextView;
            import android.widget.Toast;

            public class Grade1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
            TextView tvQuestion,tvQuestionId,tvPlayer1,tvScore,tvMissCount;
            EditText et;
            Button submit,next,start;
            Cursor c;
            MediaPlayer sonic;
            Handler mHandler = new Handler();
            long startTime;
            TextView timer,timems;
            long elapsedTime;
            final int REFRESH_RATE = 100;
            String hours,minutes,seconds,milliseconds;
            long secs,mins,hrs,msecs;
            boolean stopped = false;
            String s,timers;
            int score=1;
            int miss=1;
            dbHelp dbh = new dbHelp(this);
            ArrayList<Integer> rdm = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.grade1);
                sonic = MediaPlayer.create(Grade1.this,R.raw.sonic);
                sonic.start();
                sonic.setLooping(true);
                sonic.setVolume(100, 100);
                initialize();   

                }
            public void updateTimer (float time){
                secs = (long)(time/1000);
                mins = (long)((time/1000)/60);
                hrs = (long)(((time/1000)/60)/60);


                secs = secs % 60;
                seconds=String.valueOf(secs);
                if(secs == 0){
                    seconds = "00";
                }
                if(secs <10 && secs > 0){
                    seconds = "0"+seconds;
                }



                mins = mins % 60;
                minutes=String.valueOf(mins);
                if(mins == 0){
                    minutes = "00";
                }
                if(mins <10 && mins > 0){
                    minutes = "0"+minutes;
                }


                hours=String.valueOf(hrs);
                if(hrs == 0){
                    hours = "00";
                }
                if(hrs <10 && hrs > 0){
                    hours = "0"+hours;
                }


                milliseconds = String.valueOf((long)time);
                if(milliseconds.length()==2){
                    milliseconds = "0"+milliseconds;
                }
                if(milliseconds.length()<=1){
                    milliseconds = "00";
                }
                //milliseconds = milliseconds.substring(milliseconds.length(), milliseconds.length());

                (timer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTime)).setText(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
                //((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTimeMs)).setText(":" + milliseconds);
            }
            public Runnable startTimer = new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                       updateTimer(elapsedTime);
                       mHandler.postDelayed(this,REFRESH_RATE);
                    }
                };
                public void startClick (View view){
                    if(stopped){
                        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - elapsedTime;
                    }
                    else{
                        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(startTimer);
                    mHandler.postDelayed(startTimer, 0);
                }
                  public void stopClick (View view){
                        mHandler.removeCallbacks(startTimer);
                        stopped = true;
                    }

                    public void resetClick (View view){
                        stopped = false;
                        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTime)).setText("00:00:00");
                        //((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTimeMs)).setText(":0");
                    }
            private void refresh(){

                c = dbh.getAllGrade1();
                c.moveToPosition(rdm.get(0));
                rdm.remove(0);
                tvScore.setText(dbh.getScore(score));
                tvMissCount.setText(dbh.getMistakes(miss));
                tvPlayer1.setText(s);   
                //tvQuestion.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Question")));
                tvQuestion.setText(c.getString(1));
                et.setText("");
            }


            private void initialize() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                submit= (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
                //tvQuestionId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvQuestionId);
                tvPlayer1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPlayer1);
                tvScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvScore);
                tvQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvQuestion);
                tvMissCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMissCount);
                start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
                et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
                Intent z = getIntent();
                s = z.getExtras().getString("PlayerName");
                submit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                et.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tvQuestion.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                //Bundle receive = getIntent().getExtras();
                //hold =  receive.getString("PlayerName")

                for(int count=0; count<10; count++){
                    rdm.add(count);
                }
                Collections.shuffle(rdm);
                refresh();
                final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.answerright);
                final MediaPlayer mp2= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.answerwrong);

                start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (start.isClickable()){
                            et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            submit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            tvQuestion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            startClick(arg0);
                            start.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                });
                submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You need to answer first the question before proceeding to the next question", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Answer")).equalsIgnoreCase(et.getText().toString())){
                                mp.start();
                                if(score==10){
                                    stopClick(v);
                                     timers = timer.getText().toString();

                                //  dbh.insertRecord1(s, score,timers,miss);
                                    resetClick(v);
                                    AlertDialog diaBox = makneAndShowDialogBox();
                                    diaBox.show();
                                    diaBox.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

                                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Congratulations!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    sonic.release();
                                    //Intent a = new Intent(Grade1.this,Menu.class);
                                    //startActivity(a);
                                    //finish();
                                }
                                String Score = tvScore.getText().toString();
                                score++;
                                //String newScore = dbh.getScore(score);
                                refresh();
                            }
                            else{
                            mp2.start();
                            String Miss = tvMissCount.getText().toString();
                            miss++; 
                        //  String newMiss = dbh.getMistakes(miss);
                            refresh();
                            }
                        }




                }
                });
            }
                private AlertDialog makneAndShowDialogBox() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    AlertDialog myDialogBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Congratulations!!") 
                    .setMessage("Congratulations on finishing the game!")
                    .setPositiveButton("Main Menu", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) { 
                            Intent i = new Intent(Grade1.this,Menu.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }

                })

                .create();
                return myDialogBox;






            /** next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int count = 0;
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(count==40){
                            Intent a = new Intent(Grade1.this,Menu.class);
                            startActivity(a);
                            finish();
                        }
                        count++;
                    refreshgame();
                    }
                });

            **/


                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPause() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            super.onPause();
                            sonic.release();
                            finish();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`dbHelp dbh = new dbHelp(this);` put this line in `OnCreate`.

Comment: the problem is you are passing null context to the dbHelp, try to find out, why your context is null;